# How to stop Endnote omitting the year for some references?

Tags: citations, writing-style, reference-managers

I am having problems with Endnote outputting a mix of citation styles (or possibly a broken citation style!) in the same document, despite applying the Endnote Frontiers Science style (official, from the Endnote website) throughout. Eg

> ...feline herpesvirus 1 (Thiry et al.) and terrapene herpesvirus 1-associated pneumonia in Eastern box turtles (Sim et al., 2014)...

and when I look at the final reference list I see that both references look correct and the same eg

> Thiry, E., Addie, D., Belak, S., Boucraut-Baralon, C., Egberink, H., Frymus, T., Gruffydd-Jones, T., Hartmann, K., Hosie, M.J., Lloret, A., Lutz, H., Marsilio, F., Pennisi, M.G., Radford, A.D., Truyen, U., and Horzinek, M.C. (2009). Feline herpesvirus infection. ABCD guidelines on prevention and management. J Feline Med Surg 11, 547-555.
>
> Sim, R.R., Norton, T.M., Bronson, E., Allender, M.C., Stedman, N., Childress, A.L., and Wellehan, J.F., Jr. (2014). Identification of a novel herpesvirus in captive Eastern box turtles (Terrapene carolina carolina). Vet Microbiol.

So I am at bit of a loss as to why one reference looks correct (author, year) and the other does not (author).

Comment: What is the precise name of the journal style?

Answer (score 2):

A few options:

1. It is possible to exclude the year from an in text citation in Endnote. So I'd check that setting. Right clicking the in-text citation should give you a few options.
2. Make sure you are showing field codes in Word so that you can confirm that you have actually inserted a citation there. Without field codes it's possible that you have written some text manually.
3. You may want to explore the style settings in Endnote (e.g., go to `edit - output styles` in Endnote and select the current Endnote style). There are a whole range of settings that you may need to explore. There might be some rules that you can tweak related to how in text citations display.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know Endnote in specific, I have seen this type of failure mode in other citation software.  Typically, it happens because the software is treating the reference as the wrong *type* of reference, e.g., confusing a book chapter with a journal article.

I don't know if your example is the real references, but I notice that first has volume/issue, and page/doi information, but the second does not.  This leads me to suspect that Endnote is treating the first reference as a journal article and the second as something different.  That may be where to start looking for the problem...